# how to create login form using ruby on rails in ruby mine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

How to create a login form using ruby on rails in rubymine?? i want fields such as username and password and a submit button.when the user clicks submit button username and password must be checked against a mysql database.if the username or password don't match then there must not be login but if the username and password do match it should be redirected to a page. how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

One of the best methods to authenticate a USER against Username and Password :

**1. Authlogic**

[RailsCast : Authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic)

[RailsCast : Authlogic : Asciicast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic?view=asciicast)

**2. Devise**

[RailsCast : Devise](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

Answer (score 0):

Learn Ruby on Rails from [Ruby On Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org)

See the [sign in section](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec-signin_form) in the same tutorial